# slider over list view navigate to new url

Tags: android, slider

I tried to place an image slider over a `ListView`. When I click on that slider's images I want to hit different URL's for different images.

Here is my code

```
    Hash_file_maps.put("Android Donut", "http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/9-credit-1.jpg");
    Hash_file_maps.put("Android Eclair", "http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/canberra_hero_image_JiMVvYU.jpg");
    Hash_file_maps.put("Android Froyo", "http://androidblog.esy.es/images/froyo-4.png");
    Hash_file_maps.put("Android GingerBread", "http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/6775415-beautiful-images.jpg");

    for(String name : Hash_file_maps.keySet()) {

        TextSliderView textSliderView = new TextSliderView(MainActivity.this);
        textSliderView
                // .description(name)
                .image(Hash_file_maps.get(name))
                // .setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.Fit)
                .setOnSliderClickListener(this);
        textSliderView.bundle(new Bundle());
        // textSliderView.getBundle().putString("extra",name);
        sliderLayout.addSlider(textSliderView);
    }
    sliderLayout.setPresetTransformer(SliderLayout.Transformer.Stack);
   // sliderLayout.setPresetIndicator(SliderLayout.PresetIndicators.Center_Bottom);
    sliderLayout.setCustomAnimation(new DescriptionAnimation());
    sliderLayout.setDuration(5000);
    sliderLayout.addOnPageChangeListener(this);
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i placed slider layout over list view i  get slider images in un sequencial order means (getting data in one order and display slide in another order

Comment: thanks for try to help me. And here is the code link     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43256667/sequential-order-for-slider-over-listview

Comment: so now you created a duplicate of your own question? You can remove the duplicate...