# sequential order for slider over listview

Tags: android, slider

I am new to android and i tried to load images for slider over listview dynamically,but i am getting in nonsequensial order(means getting in one order and shows in another order.

here is my code

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObjectAD = new JSONObject(s);

            jsonArrayAD = jsonObjectAD.getJSONArray("images");

            for(int i=0;i<jsonArrayAD.length();i++) {

                JSONObject jsonObject7 = jsonArrayAD.getJSONObject(i);
                ADUrl = jsonObject7.getString("image");
                ADUrl2 = "";
                ADUrl3 =ADUrl2.concat(ADUrl);
                ADName = jsonObject7.getString("advTitle");
                ADId = jsonObject7.getString("advLink");

                ADCatName.add(ADName);
                ADCatImage.add(ADUrl3);
                 ADCatId.add(ADId);

          Hash_file_maps.put(ADId,ADUrl3);
                //Toast.makeText(getApplication(),""+ADId,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            for(String name : Hash_file_maps.keySet()) {

                textSliderView = new TextSliderView(MainActivity.this);

                textSliderView
                        // .description(name)
                        .image(Hash_file_maps.get(name)).setOnSliderClickListener(this);
                textSliderView.bundle(new Bundle());
                 textSliderView.getBundle().putString("extra",name);
                sliderLayout.addSlider(textSliderView);
            }
            sliderLayout.setPresetTransformer(SliderLayout.Transformer.Stack);
             sliderLayout.setPresetIndicator(SliderLayout.PresetIndicators.Center_Bottom);
            sliderLayout.setCustomAnimation(new DescriptionAnimation());
            sliderLayout.setDuration(5000);
            sliderLayout.addOnPageChangeListener(this);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be in order. A map's keySet function returns a Set and the set's iterator method says this in its documentation:

"Returns an iterator over the elements in this set. The elements are returned in no particular order (unless this set is an instance of some class that provides a guarantee)."

So, unless you are using one of those classes with a guarantee, there is none.